Monotone grand coupling of Markov chains
A stochastic matrix $P$ on a finite poset $(\mathcal X,\preceq)$ is called monotone if $Pf$ is increasing whenever $f$ is. This property ensures the existence of a monotone coupling: specifically, given any two states $x,y\in\mathcal X$ with $x\preceq y$, one can construct two $P-$Markov chains $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with initial conditions $X_0=x$ and $Y_0=y$ such that $$\mathbb P(\forall n\ge 0, X_n\preceq Y_n)=1.$$
My question is: can we actually get a monotone grand coupling? That is, can we jointly construct the random variables $(X^x_n)_{n\ge 0,x\in\mathcal X}$ in such a way that

For each $x\in\mathcal X$, $(X^x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is a $P-$Markov chain starting from $X^x_0=x$.
We have $\mathbb P(\forall n\ge 0, X_n^x\preceq X_n^y) =1$ whenever $x\preceq y$.

Such a monotone grand coupling is easy to construct in all examples of monotone chains I can think of, but I do not see a general argument. Perhaps there is an easy counter-example?

Unfortunately, no, a pairwise monotone coupling does not imply the existence of a monotone grand coupling.
As you have noticed, for a transition matrix $P$ operating on a poset $(\mathcal{X}, \preceq)$ there are two different concepts of monotonicity:

$P$ is (stochastically) monotone, if for each $x \preceq y$ we have $P(x, \cdot) \preceq P(y, \cdot)$, i.e. for each upset $I\subset \mathcal{X}$ we have $\sum_{s\in I} P(x, s) \leq \sum_{s\in I} P(y, s)$. By Strassen's Theorem, this is equivalent to the existence of two random variables $X\sim P(x, \cdot)$ and $Y\sim P(y, \cdot)$ with $\mathbb{P}[X \leq Y] = 1$ for each $x\prec y$, and hence equivalent to the existence of a pairwise monotone coupling as you describe it.

P is completely monotone or realizably monotone if there is a family of random variables $(X_x\;:\;x\in\mathcal{X})$, each distributed as $X_x \sim P(x, \cdot)$ so that for each $x\preceq y$ we have $\mathbb{P}[X_x \leq X_y] = 1$. Equivalently, there exists a monotone grand coupling.


While realizable monotonicity clearly implies stochastic monotonicity, the reverse is not true. In fact, it was shown that both notions are equivalent if and only if $(\mathcal{X}, \preceq)$ is acyclic (Allen & Machida, Stochastic Monotonicity and Realizable Monotonicity, 2001).
See also this wonderful preprint, which summarizes the difference between both notions in the discrete case: (Dai Pra, Minelli, Louis, Complete monotone coupling for Markov processes, 2008).
If you are aiming for an application of coupling from the past (Propp & Wilson, 1996) and your transition matrix is monotone but not realizably monotone, you may try to apply the method described by (Fill, An interruptible algorithm for perfect sampling via Markov chains, 1998) instead.
